# Rails: validation of a group of items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a model `Tag`, and there could be an hierarchy of several `Tag`s: i.e. some `Tag` could be a super- or sub-tag of another tag, and so on.

Note: there is **not** one large tree of tags; it's just many single tags, and sometimes one tag is super-tag for another one or several tags. It works fine already.

Each `Tag` also `belongs_to :user`.

There is a constraint: all the `Tag`s in the hierarchy should belong to the same `User`.
I tried to implement this constraint via Rails validation system, but I failed. Let's see why:

To check the owner of each tag in the hierarchy, I should recursively fetch all the super- and sub-tags of the particular tag before saving it.

Assume we have a simple hierarchy of 3 tags:

```
tag1 -> tag2 -> tag3
```

Each of these tags belongs to the same user (say, "user1").

One day, I need to change the owner to "user2". It's actually impossible if users are checked through the whole hierarchy before saving each tag.

Say, I try to do something like this:

```
tag1.owner = user2
tag2.owner = user2
tag3.owner = user2
```

and then save each tag. But when I try to save the first tag, all other aren't saved yet, and user stored in the DB for these tags is "user1". Validation fails.

The solution could be to save all the tags at once (as a single "transaction"), then check all the tags affected by this transaction, and if all of them are valid, then commit transaction; otherwise rollback it. It would be just perfect, and it can look syntactically somehow like this:

```
tag1.owner = user2
tag2.owner = user2
tag3.owner = user2

transaction do
   tag1.save
   tag2.save
   tag3.save
end
```

And this is it! But, as far as I know, nothing similar is supported in Rails yet. But, what is the best practice to do what I need? Currently I just disabled this validation, but I don't really like this "solution".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about best practices, but since no one else has answered and it's been a while, I thought I'd post that you can do:

```
tag1.owner = user2
tag2.owner = user2
tag3.owner = user2

tag1.transaction do
   tag1.save!
   tag2.save!
   tag3.save!
end
```

because

- Transactions are "per database connection" and the `transaction` method is defined as both a class and instance method of `ActiveRecord::Base`
- Unlike `save`, `save!` is not itself wrapped in a transaction

as discussed in http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html